# SQL Server 2014 - Simulation and CTE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, common-table-expression, montecarlo

I am currently trying to create a simulation of two players playing dice. As you can see from the code, each player plays 2 dice, three consecutive times (a total of 6 IDs). I would like to add two additional columns:

1) Column "Result": that shows who wins "win" or loses "loss" for each of the three matches. I tried using joins but I was not able to make it. The first row should show "Win" if in Columns "Sum" the amount is major than the amount in the second row, which should then show "Loss"

2) Column "Match": which shows the specific number of the simulation. For example the first two line will be equal to "Simulation 1", the third and fourth line will be equal to "Simulation 2". Given the limited amount of rows I could do it with a case when but I would like something more dynamic, in case I decide to increase the number of simulations.

```
    with cte as
(
select 1 Id,
1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die1,
1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die2
union  all
select Id + 1,  
1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die1,
1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die2
from cte
where 
    id < 6
), 
cte2 as
(
select *,a.Die1+a.Die2 as Sum,
case when a.id=0 then 'Null'
when a.id%2=1 then '1' 
else '2' end as Player
from cte a
)
Select a.*
from cte2 a

OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[image]

Please apologies but I am still learning SQL!

Comment: Expected results would help

Comment: I added a picture at the end with the desired result

Comment: I don't understand your desired result. Do you want 6 rows with a total of 3 results ?

Comment: @riversus, save my added picture so everyone can see. Basically there are 3 'games' or 'Match' and OP wants to show who wins for each 'game\match'. I redlined between each game/match.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk can you see the picture?

Comment: Personally I would make some tables to hold some data. Then it can be as dynamic as you want. When you generate all the data on the fly like this you are going to struggle making it dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you need. You may find a more readable method using sqlserver 2012 or newer:

```
DECLARE @matches INT = 3

;WITH N1(N)AS(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))n(N)),
N2(N)AS(SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3(N)AS(SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
N4(ID)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1.N) FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)
, CTE as
(
  SELECT
    id,
    1 + floor(6 * rand(checksum(NEWID()))) Die1,
    1 + floor(6 * rand(checksum(NEWID()))) Die2
  FROM n4
  WHERE id <= @matches * 2
)
SELECT 
  *,
  Die1+Die2 as Sum,
  CASE WHEN id%2=1 then 1
  ELSE 2 end as Player, 
  Results = 
    CASE 
      sign(sum(CASE WHEN id %2 = 0 THEN - die1 - die2 ELSE die1 + die2 END)
        over (partition by (id- 1)/2)) * (id%2 * 2 - 1)
    WHEN -1 THEN 'Loss' WHEN 0 THEN 'Draw' WHEN 1 THEN 'Win' END,
  Match = (ID + 1) / 2
FROM CTE
```

Comment: That's exactly right. Would you be so kind to add a couple of comments to explain the query? Only if you want. It would make easier for me to fully understand

Comment: More simple than mine :) Well written

Answer (score 1):

This isnt the most pretty answer but this what i could come up with help from David Browne:

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dices](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [die1] [int] NULL,
    [die2] [int] NULL,
    [sum] [int] NULL,
    [Player] [int] NULL,
    [Match] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**SQL Code**

```
with thousandRows as
(
  select 0 i
  from (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(i)
  cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(i)
  cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(i)
), iterations as
(
  select top (14) row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
  from thousandRows t0, thousandRows t1 

), outcome as
(
  select i id,
  1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die1,
  1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die2
  from iterations
)


select *,a.Die1+a.Die2 as Sum,
case when a.id=0 then 'Null'
when a.id%2=1 then '1' 
else '2' end as Player
into #temp
from outcome a

;
Truncate table dices;

declare @Id int
declare @die1 int
declare @die2 int
declare @sum int
declare @Player nvarchar(50)
declare @match int = 1
declare @SetMatch int

DECLARE player1Cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT id,die1,die2,[sum],player from #temp 

where player = 1 order by id

OPEN player1Cur

FETCH NEXT FROM player1Cur
INTO @Id,@die1,@die2,@sum,@Player

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


BEGIN

SET @SetMatch = @match
insert into dices
select @id,@die1,@die2,@sum,@Player,@SetMatch

SET @match = @match +1

END 


    FETCH NEXT FROM player1Cur
    INTO  @Id,@die1,@die2,@sum,@Player
END
CLOSE player1Cur
DEALLOCATE player1Cur



SET @SetMatch = 0
SET @match = 1

DECLARE player2Cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT id,die1,die2,[sum],player from #temp 

where player = 2 order by id

OPEN player2Cur

FETCH NEXT FROM player2Cur
INTO @Id,@die1,@die2,@sum,@Player

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


BEGIN

SET @SetMatch = @match
insert into dices
select @id,@die1,@die2,@sum,@Player,@SetMatch

SET @match = @match +1

END 


    FETCH NEXT FROM player2Cur
    INTO  @Id,@die1,@die2,@sum,@Player
END
CLOSE player2Cur
DEALLOCATE player2Cur
;

select *,case when Rank() over(partition by match order by [sum] desc) = 1 then 'Win' Else 'Loss' end as WinLoss from dices
order by match,player

;
Drop table #temp
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: In advance  - Sorry for cursor abuse, but it executes 1000 rows less than a second

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and faster way to do this sort of thing in SQL Server is to use a sequence table, instead of a recursive CTE.  Something like this:

```
with thousandRows as
(
  select 0 i
  from (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(i)
  cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(i)
  cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(i)
), iterations as
(
  select top (100000) row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
  from thousandRows t0, thousandRows t1 

), outcome as
(
  select i id,
  1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die1,
  1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) Die2
  from iterations
)
select *,a.Die1+a.Die2 as Sum,
case when a.id=0 then 'Null'
when a.id%2=1 then '1' 
else '2' end as Player
from outcome a
```

Comment: That's cool and runs super fast, but still doesn't solve OP's problem. :-)